# Почему не стартует корутина при onStart() активити?

Tags: android, kotlin, асинхронность, coroutine

Такая ситуация: мне нужно сохранять данные в Firebase. Я это делаю фоново с помощью корутины. Сейчас она запускается в методы onCreate(). А мне нужно сделать так, чтобы при onStop() она заканчивала свою работу, а при onStart() снова запускалась.

Проблема в том, что при onStop() она прекращает работу, но потом при onStart() не запускается:(
В чём может быть загвоздка? Есть какое-нибудь решение? Спасибо.

Пример кода:

```
private val SaveFirebaseData = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default).launch {
    while (this.isActive) {
        try {
            delay(15000)
            SaveUserDataOnFirebase(applicationContext)
        }
        catch (e: Exception) { println(e) }
    }
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    SaveFirebaseData.start()
}

override fun onStop() {
    super.onStop()
    SaveFirebaseData.cancel()
}

override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()
    SaveFirebaseData.start()
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    SaveFirebaseData.cancel()
}
```

Comment: Судя по https://stackoverflow.com/q/58341909/3212712 нельзя запустить остановленное. Вместо этого надо новое создавать

Comment: @ЮрийСПб интересно)) Но почему тогда при onDestroy() и onCreate() работает как надо) Придётся покопаться

Comment: Ааа. Видимо когда срабатывает onDestroy(), он полностью потом пересоздает активити. Соответственно, пересоздается и задача. Поэтому работает. Буду искать способ пересоздавать задачу.

Answer (score 3):

Как указали в комментарии, запустить корутину после `cancel` уже нельзя.

Добавьте lifecycle-runtime зависимость (текущая стабильная версия 2.2.0)

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
```

Данная библиотека добавляет для активити и фрагментов свойство `lifecycleScope`. Это специальный `CoroutineScope` который привязан к жизненному циклу активити/фрагмента. Также там будет функция `launchWhenStarted`, которая запускает корутину при

> at least `Lifecycle.State.STARTED`

Т.е. с момента `onStart` и до `onStop`. В `onStope` корутина приостанавливается и ждёт `onStart`

```
private val SaveFirebaseData = lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {
    withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
        while (this.isActive) {
            try {
                delay(15000)
                SaveUserDataOnFirebase(applicationContext)
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                println(e)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Теперь можно удалить все `SaveFirebaseData.start()` и `SaveFirebaseData.cancel()`, всю работу по остановке и отмене задачи делают `lifecycleScope` и `launchWhenStarted`